# Strange problem with Sunspot. 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, rspec, sunspot

I have model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

And:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :topic_id
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

In my `topic_spec.rb`:

```
  it "should have the right associated comment" do
      @topic.comments.should include(@comment)
    end

    it "should destroy associated comments" do
      @topic.destroy
      Comment.find_by_id(@comment.id).should be_nil
    end
```

And I receive following errors:

```
1)   Failure/Error: @topic.comments.should == @comment
     NameError:
       undefined method `inspect' for class `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy'
```

---

```
2) Failure/Error: Comment.find_by_id(@comment.id).should be_nil
   expected: nil
        got: #<Comment id: 1, body: "first", created_at: "2011-08-18 09:55:06", updated_at: "2011-08-18 09:55:06">
```

What I doing wrong? This errors appeared after I started using sunspot.

In my topic.rb:

```
  searchable :auto_index => true, :auto_remove => true do
    text :title, :boost => 5
    text :description

    text :comments do
      comments.map(&:body)
    end
  end
```

If I commented this lines:

```
#    text :comments do
#      comments.map(&:body)
#    end
```

All tests successfully pass!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding following lines in `spec_helper.rb`:

```
  config.before(:each) do
    ::Sunspot.session = ::Sunspot::Rails::StubSessionProxy.new(::Sunspot.session)
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    ::Sunspot.session = ::Sunspot.session.original_session
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are comparing an array (`@topic.comments`) and an object (`@comment`) with ==. You should check if the object is contained in the array:

```
@topic.comments.should include(@comment)
```

Comment: It looks like @zolter changed some of the question text to reflect this answer. Zolter, has this changed the outcome at all ?